# Divide an odd size array into into two equal sets of same size and same sum after deleting any one element from the array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of odd size. You have to delete any one element from the array and then find whether it is possible to divide the remaining even size array into two sets of equal size and having same sum of their elements. It is mandatory to remove any one element from the array.

Comment: in the given problem is it necessary to remove any one element .? I mean what if I can divide the array in 2 equal-sum halves without removing any element..?? Shall I consider that as a solution.??

Comment: and also please give complete constraints of the problem like size of the array and maximum value of any element in the array.

Comment: @Roshan This question was from Techgig site and the size of array was upto 100000. That's why solving it through subset sum problem seemed to be costly because it has  O(n*sum) time complexity.

Comment: What is the maximum value of the element in the array.. ?

Comment: I can think of a recursive solution.
lets say solve(idx,s,val) represents the state of the problem. Here idx is the index of the current element, s total sum produced and val is value of the index which we are dropping. Then at each step we have two options either to include this element in any of the half or to drop. and then recursively find the min difference between the two halves and see if it is zero or not.

Comment: I can give a pseudo-code if u ask, but I guess it will be difficult to memoize the state if the constraints are very large (i.e. not able to fit in 10^7 in c++).

Comment: There was no any mention of the maximum value of array element (poor question formation) . Please provide your pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

So Here I am assuming that it is necessary to remove 1 element from the array.

Please look at the code snippet below.

```
int solve(int idx, int s, int cntr, int val) {
 if(idx == n)
    if(cntr != 1)
        return INT_MAX;
    else 
        return abs((sum-val)-2*s);

 int ans = INT_MAX;
 if(cntr == 0)
    ans = min(ans, solve(idx+1, s, cntr+1, arr[idx]));
 else 
    ans = min(ans, min(solve(idx+1,s+arr[idx], cntr, val),   solve(idx+1, s, cntr, val)));
 return ans;  
}
```

Here `sum` is the total sum of original array,
`val` is the
value of the element at any position which u want to delete, and `cntr` to keep track whether any value is removed from the array or not.

So the algo goes like this.

Forget that you need to delete any value, Then the problem becomes whether is it possible to divide the array into 2 equi-sum halves. Now we can think of this problem such as divide the array into 2 parts such that `abs(sum-2*sum_of_any_half_part)` is minimized. So With this idea Lets say I initially have a bucket `s` which can be the part of array which we are concerned about. So at each step we can either put any element into this part or leave it for the other part.

Now if we introduce the deletion part in to this problem, its just one small changes which is required. Now at each step instead of 2 you have 3 options.

1. To delete this particular element and then increase the `cntr` to 1 and the `val` to the value of the element at that index in the array.
2. don't do any thing with this element. This is equal to putting this element into other bucket/half
3. put this element into bucket `s`, i.e. increase value of s by `arr[idx]`;

Now recursively check which gives the best result.

P.S. Look at the base case in the code snippet to have better idea.

In the end if the above `solve` function gives ans = 0 then that means yes we can divide the array into 2 equi-sum parts after deleting any element.

Hope this helps.